# Android EditText draw a divider line between its drawable and its text

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-drawable

I have an `EditText` with a `drawableLeft` image. I need to add a vertical line in `EditText` right beside my `drawableLeft` like this example:

[image]

Easiest way that I can think of is to add that line into my drawable image. But generally is there any other way to do this?

Comment: All other way to achieve this will be more complicated. Best way is to add that line in drawable only.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Create a rectangular rounded corner shape in res/drawable/shape.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
   <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
   <padding android:left="10dip" android:top="10dip" android:right="10dip"        android:bottom="10dip" />
   </shape>
   ```
2. Now create a layout

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/shape"
   android:gravity="center_vertical">


   <ImageView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/imageView"
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

   <View
   android:layout_width="2dp"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

   <EditText
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/editText"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:background="@null"
   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
   android:hint="Your bitcoin address here"/>


   </LinearLayout>
   ```
3. I have set the Linear layout background with th rectangular rounded corner shape. It looks exactly as the image preview of urs.

Comment: This totally works. Never thought of doing it this way. Thanks

Comment: @abeikverdi: glad it helped u :) Plz accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `layout` and attache to the editText as a property

```
android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/your_layout"
```

for example

```
<EditText 
   android:width="match_parent"
   android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/your_layout"
/>
```

in your `your_layout.xml` file you can put anything you want.

Please check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableLeft)

Comment: ah right. I can pass a drawable there. Totally miss that! That's cool. It will be great if you add a simple code for your_layout.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this , your issue solved

In your **.xml file** ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:minHeight="40dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_clear_to"
                android:layout_width="30dip"
                android:layout_height="30dip"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_delete" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/vvv1"
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.8"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_to"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:text="@string/text_to"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal_size" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**customborder.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:radius="2dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/black" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple!

Just add a '`FrameLayout`'

```
 <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/vertical_divider"
            android:layout_width="2dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/<your_object>"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/<your_object>"
            android:background="@color/grey" />
```

Replace `<your_object>` with your drawable image.